# Prohibited content in Azure Devops

Tags: azure, azure-devops

I have several questions:

1. Can I include in a project repository my own EULA\License text for the source codes?
2. Can I use Azure DevOps for free and open-sourced projects?

Because [here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/support/legal/devops-code-of-conduct/) from what I can see, I cannot use Azure DevOps in these cases. Is that correct?

Comment: What specific items of the list are you referring to?

Comment: @PeterBons Free Offers and Terms of Use

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regarding questions 1 and 2, please check the description below:

We recommend that you host your source code on github and use Azure Devops for continuous integration/continuous deployment (CI/CD). This is because Azure DevOps Public Projects aren't generally discoverable to the general public. A project member needs to publicize the URL for it to be found.

You could use Azure DevOps for free and open-sourced projects. An Azure DevOps Services public project provides support to share code with others and to support continuous integration/continuous deployment (CI/CD) of open-source software. Users aren't required to sign in to gain read-only access to many of the services.

You could refer to this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/public/about-public-projects?view=azure-devops) to view more detailed information about public project.

Because here from what I can see, I cannot use Azure DevOps in these cases. Is that correct?

Your understanding is correct. The entry of the Code of Conduct is to build a better Azure Devops and let our users get a better experience.